# Can I fly between Sweden and Germany without an ID card?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, germany, sweden

I'll be flying from Sweden to Germany, and back, so within the Schengen area. Only problem is that the only form of ID I have is an expired national identity card from Sweden. I am a Swedish citizen.

Will this be a problem? Will I not be allowed to pass through security or board the plane? Would getting a temporary passport help?

Comment: Maybe related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141401/must-a-traveler-carry-their-passport-in-the-netherlands-belgium-and-france

Comment: You are required to carry a valid travel document both when entering and leaving Germany, even if there are no regular immigration checks. You are also required to be in possesion of a valid travel document while you are staying in Germany (not only for passing the border). Airlines may or may not check your id at the airport, but even if you are let onto the plane, you risk at least more or less hassle in Germany, if you for some reason should end up in a situation where the authorities want to see some form of id.

Answer (score 0):

Airlines use the Timatic database to assess what documents a passenger must produce in order to board. There are several public portals to Timatic; this answer used [this one](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html).

Germany > Sweden:

Here's Timatic's report for this flight:

[image]

Thus, you must show either a passport, Swedish national ID card, or a Swedish termporary passport...and that doc must be valid on arrival. With only an expired Swedish ID card, the airline is likely to refuse to board you.

Sweden > Germany:

For a Swedish citizen, this is almost  same. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

The difference is that for this flight, no "temporary passport" method is listed.

Comment: While Schengen does allow you to travel without showing your passport or ID card, it does not do away with the rule that you should have one of them when you cross borders.

Comment: Airlines are not required to check ids on intra-schengen flights and many airlines don't. In my experience, SAS or Lufthansa most likely won't, but low-cost airlines usually want to se some form of id when passengers are checking in or boarding, not to fulfill immigration requirements, but to verify that the passenger is actually flying with his own ticket and is not trying to evade any lucrative name change fees.

Comment: As a general rule, the Schengen member states recognize the national ID cards of other Schengen states, so you don't need a passport in that case.

Comment: The OP's national ID card is expired. Will they recognize that one?

Comment: @Janka That is in case of Sweden not the entire truth. Swedish authorities issue several different id cards, all casually called 'national id cards' and not all of them are valid abroad. The 'proper' national id card, also valid in other EU countries, is only held by anout 10% of the population.